# Want to port from iPad to iPhone. How to resize viewcontrollers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I helped create an app that was designed for iPad.  This app has hundreds of viewcontrollers designed in uibuilder.  We would now like to create a version for iPhone, but when we simulate it an iPhone only a portion of each viewcontroller fits in the screen.  Does anyone know a way we can resize these viewcontrollers so that we don't have to redesign them?

Comment: SizeClass/AutoLayout?

Comment: Did you use size classes and AutoLayout? If not, you have a big job ahead of you.

Comment: Even with autolayout this may be time consuming in trying to squeeze everything onto the smaller screen. Especially iphone 4s.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a shot in the dark, I cannot comment to ask for more information, but in your storyboard, at the bottom of the screen will display something like wRegular hRegular or wAny hAny. If it is working for iPads but not for iPhones, I am assuming it is set to wRegular hRegular. Try setting it to wAny hAny.